# Predict the density of wine given its acidity using gradient descent algorithm (poor training accuracy)

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm currently working on implementing a least squares linear regression model in Python to predict wine density based on its acidity. I'm facing some challenges with my current implementation - poor training accuracy. Let me show you the plot of training data (X,Y) where X is the acidity of wine and Y is the density of wine: [blue: training data, red: hypothesis using my approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH6hg.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv('linearX.csv').values
Y = pd.read_csv('linearY.csv').values
theta = np.array([0.0, 0.0])

def descend(x, y, w, b, learning_rate):
    dldw = 0.0  # derivative with respect to theta[0]
    dldb = 0.0  # derivative with respect to theta[1]
    N = x.shape[0]
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
        dldw += (-1) * xi * (yi - (w * xi + b))
        dldb += (-1) * (yi - (w * xi + b))
    w = w - learning_rate * dldw * (1/N)
    b = b - learning_rate * dldb * (1/N)
    return w, b

while ((Y - (theta[0] + theta[1]*X)).sum() > 0.0000001):
    theta[0], theta[1] = descend(X, Y, theta[0], theta[1], 0.01)

print("Optimal theta:", theta)

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.scatter(X, theta[0] + theta[1] * X, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Can anyone please help me get close to the actual Y? What is so wrong with my implementation of gradient descent that my hypothesis is so off? Please help me resolve this.